# How to switch backend configuration dynamically between local conf and Heroku distant backen on my angular App?

Tags: angular, heroku, environment-variables

I am using heroku, my app is an angular app.

When I work locally I need this configuration:

```
window.__env.config = {
  my_backend_conf: { // Lets call this local conf : the A conf
    protocol: 'http',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '8080',
    contextRoot: 'back',
  }
  /*my_backend_conf: { // Lets call this conf : the B conf (this back is on heroku)
    protocol: '{{default .Env.APP_BACKEND_PROTOCOL "http"}}',
    host: '{{default .Env.APP_BACKEND_HOST "localhost"}}',
    port: '{{default .Env.APP_BACKEND_PORT "8080"}}',
    contextRoot: '{{default .Env.APP_BACKEND_CONTEXT_ROOT "back"}}'
  }*/
 }
```

I cannot (do not want also) to use my heroku backen conf when I code in my local front. But I was expecting this : `host: '{{default .Env.APP_BACKEND_HOST "localhost"}}'` to be : use heroku backen (APP_BACKEND_HOST or "localhost" but in local, if I keep conf B It doesn't work.

I am obliged to comment conf B when I am in local, to uncomment it before deploying to heroku and comment conf A.

Any other clean conf ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment files provided by Angular.

Use `src/environments/environment.ts` for local development, and `src/environments/environments.prod.ts` for production.

When you do `ng build --configuration=production`, Angular knows that it has to use the configuration present in environment.prod.ts.